# a collection of ValueObjects as result of a database query

Tags: domain-driven-design

Given tha nature of ValueObjects in DDD,it can be considered a collection of them as a container that contains the result set of a database query?

for example,this pseudocode could be a reasonable usage of ValueObject concept?:

```
List<ValueObject> resultSet = GetValueObjectsFromDB();

List<ValueObject> GetValueObjectsFromDB()
{
    return ExecuteCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.AnEntity");
}
```

Comment: I think services can return value objects from the DB. Things such as lookup values, etc. However, `dbo.AnEntity` makes very little sense in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you confuse Value Object which is one of the building blocks of Domain Driven Design and DTO (Data Transfert Object) which is a dumb data container.

**Value Object** : An object has no conceptual identity. They should be treated as immutable. Value Object plays his role in a **domain model** and very often have a behaviour associated with it.

**DTO** : It's just a dumb data container that can be used for transfering data on the wire or between architectural layers.

What you would use on the 'query' side is a DTOs tailored to your specific needs. If you want to display it on the screen or transfert this data to another system the DTOs is the way to do it.